# Delete clicked item of a list fetched from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, routes, axios

I want to be able to delete items of a list fetched from MongoDB.

Items of an array of the list are retrieved from MongoDB and displayed in React app.

How can I pass the id of the item that is clicked to the to DeleteListItem() function and then to axios.delete()? Thanks!

ExpensesListItem.tsx (**HERE I should pass id of the item to axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist') somehow**)

```
import React from "react";
import { IconButton, ListItem, ListItemSecondaryAction, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
import axios from 'axios';
interface Props {
    expenseTitle: string;
    expenseAmount: string;
    currencySymbol: string;
    item: ExpenseAndAmountObject;
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

const ExpensesListItem: React.FC<Props> = (
    {
        expenseTitle,
        expenseAmount,
        currencySymbol,
        item,
        expenseAndAmountList,
        setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: Props) => {

    const DeleteListItem = () => {
        setExpenseAndAmountList(expenseAndAmountList.filter(el => el._id !== item._id));

        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ListItem className="list-item">
                <ListItemText primary={expenseTitle} secondary={expenseAmount + currencySymbol} />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    <IconButton onClick={DeleteListItem} edge="end">
                        <DeleteIcon className="delete-btn" />
                    </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default ExpensesListItem;
```

routes.js

```
 router.delete('/expenseslist', (request, response) => {
    ExpenseAndAmountTemplate.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id, function(err){
        if(err){
            response.redirect("/Could not delete the item...");
        } else {
            response.redirect("/Expenses and amount item was deleted succesfully...");
        }
     });
 });

router.post('/expenseslist', (request, response) => {
    const ExpenseAndAmountItem = new ExpenseAndAmountTemplate({
     expenseTitle:request.body.expenseTitle,
     expenseAmount:request.body.expenseAmount,
 });
 ExpenseAndAmountItem.save()
 .then(data => {
     response.json(data);
 })
 .catch(error => {
     response.json(error);
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where you get your id in your DeleteListItem function, I guess the id is item._id

Otherwise I would use the body of the request to pass the id using the data parameter in axios

```
//react
const DeleteListItem = () => {
 setExpenseAndAmountList(expenseAndAmountList.filter(el => el._id !== item._id));

 //pass in the body with data
 axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', {data : { itemId: item._id }})
  .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
  });
}
```

And in your back-end you can get the id in the request.body

```
router.delete('/expenseslist', (request, response) => {
 const {itemId} = request.body
 //or request.body.itemId
 ... 
});
```

Comment: In `DeleteListItem()` function I call `setExpenseAndAmountList` in order to remove the clicked item from the list (state) so that it would be removed from the component. Since it is triggered by `onClick()`, `el` element is a clicked element (which uses an interface that has an attribute "._id")

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand how to pass an id of the clicked element to DeleteListItem()

Comment: In your code the clicked element is your button only, so before passing the id you have to retrieve it. how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Front end**

```
const ExpensesListItem: React.FC<Props> = (
    {
        expenseTitle,
        expenseAmount,
        currencySymbol,
        item,
        expenseAndAmountList,
        setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: Props) => {

    const DeleteListItem = (toBeDeletedItemId) => {
        setExpenseAndAmountList(expenseAndAmountList.filter(el => el._id !== toBeDeletedItemId));

        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/expenseslist',{itemId:toBeDeletedItemId})
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ListItem className="list-item">
                <ListItemText primary={expenseTitle} secondary={expenseAmount + currencySymbol} />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    <IconButton itemId="{item._id}" onClick={()=>DeleteListItem(item._id)} edge="end">
                        <DeleteIcon className="delete-btn" />
                    </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default ExpensesListItem;
```

**Backend**

```
router.delete('/expenseslist', (request, response) => {
    let itemId=request.body.itemId;
    ExpenseAndAmountTemplate.findByIdAndRemove(itemId, function(err){
        if(err){
            response.redirect("/Could not delete the item...");
        } else {
            response.redirect("/Expenses and amount item was deleted succesfully...");
        }
     });
 });
```

And make sure your ajax request Url must be correct.

Comment: i think axios.delete does support a request body. see [request method aliases](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) is axios.delete(url[, config]) , so you can use config.data to add in request body

Comment: Hayat, your solution seems clear to me. thanks! however, I am getting an error `Argument of type '{ itemId: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig'` in <ExpensesListItem> since I am using Typescript

Comment: I have edit my answer and change the delete to post you can try. But i think the problem is url in the axios url have extra path /app/.I don't know how you used the routes in the backend can you confirm the url is correct

Comment: Hayat, I've also edited my question and have added a post route (I cannot change the delete into post since post is already used)

Comment: grubbyGerbil i also have edited my ans.Try this once Dom is loaded inspect the delete button and check the itemId attribute.What's there in the attr value? let me know

Comment: The problem is passing the id to the delete function currently it passing undefined into the function.If we pass the correct Id then the code should work. Pass the objectID onClick={()=>DeleteListItem(item._id)}  into this function for your help i just put item._id